Varied amount of input data first time question
This is my first ever question.  I'm working on a zybooks lab (6.12.1) - I'm pretty excited that I've actually wrote the code and it mostly works - THe problem I am having is that the average I am calculating is printing out with a decimal. I struggle with formatting but if I could get a hint with how to format it so the number shows as 10 vs 10.0 I would be very grateful (I Could google the answer and I could use Stack to find it but I need some more activity to rank up)!
I tried this:
    user_input = input()
    numbers= []
    for i in user_input.split():
        numbers.append(int(i))
    print (sum(numbers)/len(numbers), max(numbers)) `

Program input 15 20 0 5
Print shows: 10.0 20
Expected: 10 20

Ok I figured out my own answer :-) user_input = input()
numbers= []
for i in user_input.split():
numbers.append(int(i))
average = (sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
max = (max(numbers))
print (int(average), max)

The division operator / will yield a floating point quotient even if the numerator and denominator are both integers. That's what you're seeing.
For your desired result use the floor division operator //
Take a look at section 6.7 here

Thank you so much! This was incredibly useful and makes so much sense!
